# Reference request for the analysis of the concept of "fact"

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request

I am looking for books and papers that analyze the concept of "fact" in a philosophical way. That is, such texts might define what a fact is, talk about whether a fact is one kind of entity in and of itself, talk about how facts differ (if they do) from truths, etc. I read the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry on facts, but I am looking for further references.

Comment: How about references at the bottom of that SEP entry, in the "bibliography"?

Comment: I don't know that anyone has a list handy, but you might want to do some work on PhilPapers: https://philpapers.org/browse/facts-and-states-of-affairs/

Comment: The answer may be found in the *mode* of *pop philosophy*

Answer (score 1):

The SEP entry [on facts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/) will be a good direct and indirect resource. There are strong connections between the concept/word "facts" and talk of [states-of-affairs](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/states-of-affairs/), and facts are the classically preeminent [truthmakers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truthmakers/).

More specific references would be the articles on various philosophers' commitments (temporary or not) to logical atomism, e.g. [Russell's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-atomism/) or [Wittgenstein's](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-atomism/).

Talk of facts is often involved in talk of [truth as in the correspondence theory of truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-correspondence/). Oftentimes, given their metaphorical {*Subject*, *predicate*} character, facts are supposed to be related to [properties](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/) (where properties are the predicates, and [substance-terms are the subjects](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/substance/)).

Answer (score 1):

David Wootton's book *The Invention of Science* devotes a chapter to the meaning of facts. In particular, he argues against Nietzsche's claim that facts, as such, are merely a matter of interpretation and, therefore, have no real existence.

Against this claim Wootton's contention is that we live and swim in an sea of *facts*, invisible, yet determining of our world.

https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Invention_of_Science/7exeBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: Can it be that (yes, it can be!!) some dogs are Alsatians and some dogs are Dobermans?